# Custom draw CTreeCtrl: how to add font strike through?

Tags: c++, mfc, fonts, custom-draw

I have implemented custom draw for an CTreeCtrl in my MFC Smart Device program.  I have successfully changed the color of specific nodes of the CTreeCtrl.  I am now trying to understand how to get the default font used to draw text in the control so I can add a strike-through to the font for certain nodes.  How would I go about getting the default font used to draw text in the CTreeCtrl and apply a font strike-through to the font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GetFont() to get the font of the control. Strike-through can't be done with ::DrawText AFAIK, but it's easy to just add a GoTo()/LineTo(). You can use GetTextExtent() to get the size of the bounding rectangle and derive the left/right of the strike through line from that.